# WPF Combobox selection is not clearing when text box inside custom combobox is focused

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom WPF combobox, on top I have textbox and below item template which will display the list of items. Now when I move mouse over the items then the respecting is getting selected, but without clicking on any item just clicking into textbox which is present inside same combobox. Now I want the selection from combobox to be cleared. Because when I type something in textbox and click on enter key then it is considering the selected item as last highlighted one. But actually if I click on textbox and typed something then i want to do different process.

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource myWhite}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource myBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16,5,10,0" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           Margin="1"
                           AllowsTransparency="true"
                           IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw"
                                                       Width="Auto"
                                                       MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                                       CornerRadius="5"
                                                       Color="Transparent">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Padding="0,1,0,0"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="#92AEC4"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="5">
                                <Grid Width="300" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                                          Width="250"
                                          Margin="8,4,8,16">
                                        <Border Height="24"
                                                BorderBrush="#656565"
                                                BorderThickness="1"
                                                CornerRadius="3">
                                            <StackPanel Margin="8,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Padding="0,0,5,0"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           FontFamily="ACE-Icon-Font"
                                                           FontSize="15"
                                                           Foreground="#656565"
                                                           Text="&#xe90d;" />
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox"
                                                             Width="{Binding ElementName=DropDownBorder, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                             Foreground="#333333"
                                                             IsEnabled="True"
                                                             Focusable="True"
                                                             Text="{Binding Path=CustNameSearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                        <TextBox.Style>
                                                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                                            </Style>
                                                        </TextBox.Style>
                                                    </TextBox>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                                          Background="Transparent"
                                          RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer"
                                                      MaxHeight="194"
                                                      Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Canvas Width="0"
                                                        Height="0"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect"
                                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                                               Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                                               Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"
                                                               Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" />
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                                <Button Margin="16,0"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                        Command="{Binding Path=HandleCommandsCommand}"
                                                        CommandParameter="AddCustDetails"
                                                        Content="Create Customer"
                                                        Visibility="{Binding Path=CreateCustButtonVisibility, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
                                                </Button>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogB"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ConPres"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      Content="Select Cust.."
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="false"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TogB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentPresenter.Style>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="PART_Popup" Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Shdw" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,3,3" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Shdw" Property="Color" Value="#16000000" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Height" Value="120" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="ConPres" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#CBCBCB" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                    </Trigger>



                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If user click on textbox inside to combobox then the selection from combobox should clear. Or EnterKey pressed on textbox then it should not select anything form combobox and should remain same.

Comment: Can you share the ComboBoxEditableTemplate code ? I would say nothing wrong with Style trigger.

Comment: I have shared my complete code, please look into it and share your thoughts